# R how to repeat an ARIMA model with specific orders (e.g. ARIMA(0,0,2)) 60 times

Tags: r

*I have already stored 60 groups of data in a list and I want to use ARIMA(0,0,2) to fit 
the data and forecast the next day. The code is shown below and it seems that 
there are some problems with ts(x). Could you please help me to solve this problem?*

```
> runArima <- function(ts){
+   Higher.R2.18. <- arima(ts,order=c(0,0,2))           
+   pred <- forecast(Higher.R2.18.,h=1)

+   return(list(arima=Higher.R2.18.,forecast=pred))

+ }

> library(forecast)
> for(i in 304:363)
+ {ts.list[i-303]<-list(mydata[2:i,4])}
> arima.list <- lapply(ts.list,runArima)
Error in ts(x) : object is not a matrix
```

Comment: `library(fortunes); fortune('dog')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use another name for your function's parameter `ts`, e.g., `x`. `ts` is the name of a function (that is used to create time-series objects). This causes the error you are seeing when the forecasting function tries to access the object `ts`.

This would then look like the following:

```
runArima <- function(x){
+   Higher.R2.18. <- arima(x,order=c(0,0,2))           
+   pred <- forecast(Higher.R2.18.,h=1)
+   return(list(arima=Higher.R2.18.,forecast=pred))
+ }
```

Comment: It seems strange to me that the function `ts` would overwrite the local variable `ts`. This is not typical behavior in R. It seems more likely to me that the problem is that the elements of `ts.list` are not vectors or matrices. Running `str(ts.list)` may clarify this.

Comment: I cannot tell you what exactly is happening here. I have had this issue multiple times already, were I named the function parameter `ts`, because it is a time-series. It always causes this exact error and simply renaming the parameter makes the problem go away. Looking at the error message makes me think that it has to do with the way `forecast` accesses the model data, which is not part of the model object created by the `arima` function, but rather stored as textual reference and then probably loaded from the environment.